# How to fix following error in R 'Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all")' while web scraping with rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to R and am currently working on an assignment dealing with web scraping.

I am supposed to read in all the sentences from this web page: https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html

This is my current code:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html'
read_html(url)
sentences <- url %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_text()
```

And everytime I run it, I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :    no applicable method for
>   'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"

Can you please help me? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to assign a variable (I imagine it was intended to be the same `url`) to `read_html(url)`. So `url %>% html_nodes("li")` is reading a "string" instead of a "xml_document", which is what the error is telling you (internally, `rvest::html_nodes` calls the function `xml2::xml_find_all`).

You could do this:

```r
html <- read_html(url)

sentences <- html%>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_text()
```

Or this, if you are reading `url` only once

```r
sentences <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_text()
```